# PHP 5.4 yum dependency issue on AWS Linux 2

Tags: php, yum

I am running PHP 8.1 on AWS Linux 2.  When I run yum updates I get the following error:

```
> Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package php.x86_64 0:5.4.16-46.amzn2.0.3 will be obsoleting
--> Processing Dependency: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-46.amzn2.0.3 for package: php-5.4.16-46.amzn2.0.3.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.16-46.amzn2.0.3 for package: php-5.4.16-46.amzn2.0.3.x86_64
---> Package php-dbg.x86_64 0:8.1.26-1.amzn2 will be obsoleted
---> Package python-lockfile.noarch 1:0.9.1-4.amzn2 will be obsoleted
---> Package python-simplejson.x86_64 0:3.2.0-1.amzn2.0.2 will be obsoleted
---> Package python2-lockfile.noarch 1:0.11.0-17.el7 will be obsoleting
---> Package python2-simplejson.x86_64 0:3.11.1-1.el7 will be obsoleting
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php-5.4.16-46.amzn2.0.3.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
           Requires: php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-46.amzn2.0.3
           Installed: php-common-8.1.26-1.amzn2.x86_64 (installed)
               php-common(x86-64) = 8.1.26-1.amzn2
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-43.amzn2.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-43.amzn2
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-43.amzn2.0.1.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-43.amzn2.0.1
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-43.amzn2.0.2.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-43.amzn2.0.2
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-43.amzn2.0.3.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-43.amzn2.0.3
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-43.amzn2.0.4.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-43.amzn2.0.4
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-45.amzn2.0.5.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-45.amzn2.0.5
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-45.amzn2.0.6.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-45.amzn2.0.6
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-46.amzn2.0.2.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-46.amzn2.0.2
           Available: php-common-5.4.16-46.amzn2.0.3.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php-common(x86-64) = 5.4.16-46.amzn2.0.3
Error: Package: php-5.4.16-46.amzn2.0.3.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
           Requires: php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.16-46.amzn2.0.3
           Installed: php-cli-8.1.26-1.amzn2.x86_64 (installed)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 8.1.26-1.amzn2
           Available: php-cli-5.4.16-43.amzn2.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.16-43.amzn2
           Available: php-cli-5.4.16-43.amzn2.0.1.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.16-43.amzn2.0.1
           Available: php-cli-5.4.16-43.amzn2.0.2.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.16-43.amzn2.0.2
           Available: php-cli-5.4.16-43.amzn2.0.3.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.16-43.amzn2.0.3
           Available: php-cli-5.4.16-43.amzn2.0.4.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.16-43.amzn2.0.4
           Available: php-cli-5.4.16-45.amzn2.0.5.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.16-45.amzn2.0.5
           Available: php-cli-5.4.16-45.amzn2.0.6.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.16-45.amzn2.0.6
           Available: php-cli-5.4.16-46.amzn2.0.2.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.16-46.amzn2.0.2
           Available: php-cli-5.4.16-46.amzn2.0.3.x86_64 (amzn2-core)
               php-cli(x86-64) = 5.4.16-46.amzn2.0.3
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I've tried removing these packages, but it says they are not installed.

```
yum remove php-5.4.16-46.amzn2.0.3.x86_64 php-common-5.4.16-46.amzn2.0.3.x86_64

> Loaded plugins: extras_suggestions, langpacks, priorities, update-motd
No Match for argument: php-5.4.16-46.amzn2.0.3.x86_64
No Match for argument: php-common-5.4.16-46.amzn2.0.3.x86_64
```

I've tried rebuilding the yum cache using these commands:

```
sudo yum clean all
sudo yum makecache
sudo yum update php
```

But this makes no difference.

Results of `yum list installed | grep php`:

```
php-bcmath.x86_64                   8.1.26-1.amzn2                   installed
php-cli.x86_64                      8.1.26-1.amzn2                   installed
php-common.x86_64                   8.1.26-1.amzn2                   installed
php-dba.x86_64                      8.1.26-1.amzn2                   installed
php-dbg.x86_64                      8.1.26-1.amzn2                   installed
php-devel.x86_64                    8.1.26-1.amzn2                   installed
php-embedded.x86_64                 8.1.26-1.amzn2                   installed
php-enchant.x86_64                  8.1.26-1.amzn2                   installed
php-fpm.x86_64                      8.1.26-1.amzn2                   installed
php-gd.x86_64                       8.1.26-1.amzn2                   installed
php-gmp.x86_64                      8.1.26-1.amzn2                   installed
php-intl.x86_64                     8.1.26-1.amzn2                   installed
php-ldap.x86_64                     8.1.26-1.amzn2                   installed
php-mbstring.x86_64                 8.1.26-1.amzn2                   installed
php-mysqlnd.x86_64                  8.1.26-1.amzn2                   installed
php-odbc.x86_64                     8.1.26-1.amzn2                   installed
php-opcache.x86_64                  8.1.26-1.amzn2                   installed
php-pdo.x86_64                      8.1.26-1.amzn2                   installed
php-pear.noarch                     1:1.10.13-1.amzn2                installed
php-pecl-imagick.x86_64             3.7.0-1.amzn2                    installed
php-pecl-imagick-devel.noarch       3.7.0-1.amzn2                    installed
php-pgsql.x86_64                    8.1.26-1.amzn2                   installed
php-process.x86_64                  8.1.26-1.amzn2                   installed
php-pspell.x86_64                   8.1.26-1.amzn2                   installed
php-snmp.x86_64                     8.1.26-1.amzn2                   installed
php-soap.x86_64                     8.1.26-1.amzn2                   installed
php-sodium.x86_64                   8.1.26-1.amzn2                   installed
php-xml.x86_64                      8.1.26-1.amzn2                   installed
```

But they are all for 8.1.26, which is why this is confusing.

```
yum autoremove
```

Has no effect.

```
yum update --obsoletes
```

Results in the same error.

```
package-cleanup --leaves && yum update
```

Results in the same error.

What am I missing?

Comment: try `yum list installed` to see what the actual package name is? The transaction check lists it as only `php.x86_64`

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Pasted above in main post...

Comment: Does `rpm -qa` show any differences? You might try `yum update --obsoletes`, `yum autoremove`, or `package-cleanup --leaves` to try and get yum to behave

Comment: @Cpt.Whale Thanks for the response.  I had tried `yum autoremove`, but I forgot to mention above.  `yum update --obsoletes` produces the same error.  `package-cleanup --leaves && yum update` produces the same error.  Thanks.

Comment: Check whether `yum check-update` or `yum list obsoletes` shows more about the dependencies causing this issue, or at least shows which package it's trying to install php5 overtop of